Set default test timeout
Is there a way to set a default timeout for test() functions using the Node.js built-in test runner?
The doc says:


timeout <number> A number of milliseconds the test will fail after. If unspecified, subtests inherit this value from their parent. Default: Infinity.


However inheriting timeout from suite is useless, because the suite will time out before the test. And I cannot find any other way to set a timeout on parent.
Example below: I want t99 to fail because it takes longer than 2 seconds. Setting 2s timeout on suite makes the test fail in t2 below, since the suite has used 2 seconds.
async function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

suite('test-timeout', /*{ timeout: 2000 },*/ function () {
    // in mocha I would do: this.timeout(2000)
    test('t1', async function () {
        await sleep(1500)
    })
    test('t2', async function () {
        await sleep(1500)
    })
    // ...
    test('t99', async function () {
        await sleep(3000)
    })
})


Any generalized API can be customized to your needs by providing wrapper functions for test, etc that use the required options, e.g:
function test(name, fn, options = {}) {
  return testModule.test(
    name,
    { timeout: globalThis.TEST_TIMEOUT || 60000, ...options },
    fn
  );
}

It will take more to cover all cases like it.only and test context in suite but it's a reasonable approach over all.
Global timeout option can be provided through yet undocumented --test-timeout command line option, but it's applied to the whole test suite.

Setting --test-timeout seems to be equivalent to setting timeout on suite(). The function will probably work, I just don't understand why it is not a simple built in feature.

Probably because it's arrived not so long ago, and probably it's barebone by design and lacks other basic functionality from existing test runners. I'd expect third-party wrappers to exist to provide additional features, but I'm not aware of them.

You can set timeout for that particular test
test(
    't99',
    {
        timeout: 2000
    },
    async function () {
        await sleep(3000);
    }
);


I understand this, but it is not very pretty to have to add that to each test case.
